# How to set an AS class as Default Application in Flex 4 Project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml, flash-builder

I'm currently working on a Flex 4 Project where I have several MXML files and a couple of AS classes. Due to the type of project the "Default Application" seems to be also an MXML instead of an AS3 class and I'm required to have the later.

Long story short, is it possible to set a given AS class as Default Application? if not, is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance,

Aldo

Comment: Flash Builder 4 Premium and by following @Imran 's directions I succeeded on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it for Flex3/Eclipse, and i think Same For Flex4 in FlashBuilder/eclipse

First you need to modify file "**.actionScriptProperties**" located in project root
to add **AS3** File as Application
if your app name is **AsApplication.as**
add tag under  if you have MXML App they would be listing here.

```
<application path="AsApplication.as"/>
```

as

```
<applications>
    <application path="AsApplication.as"/>
</applications>
```

now its visible in **project properties**
Set it as **DEFAULT**

[image]

Hopes that helps

Comment: Thank you! That just did the work. Just as a side note, I had to also change the Framework Linkage to **Merge into code** under **Flex Build Path** property.